# When installing Grub to a windows 7 install USB I get this error

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I followed everything correctly but when executing the last command I get this error

```
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.
```

So far I have followed these steps

1. Format your USB drive as NTFS using GParted
2. Copy all files from Windows ISO to USB drive using your favorite
   file manager
3. Install GRUB on USB: sudo grub-install
   --root-directory="/media/" /dev/sdX

I ran the command like this

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/media/christian/45A1483D795F007F/dev/sdb
```

Note:  The drive I am running is slowly failing.  A file could be corrupted! Please don't just assume this is the problem though.

Ugg I am totally stuck on this!

Thanks

## UPDATE

I was doing something wrong! After /media/drive I put /dev/sdb without a space! After putting a space I now get this error

```
grub-install: error: /media/christian/Windows 7/ doesn't look like an EFI partition.
```

Comment: What's the actual command you typed? Did you replace sdX with sdb or whatever you needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Avoid at all costs file paths that contain spaces. So give your USB a label without spaces!
2. The `root-directory` value is incorrect. You must specify the USB mount path, not its UUID.
3. Read [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/487970/269282) again and don't forget the `target` argument.

Comment: Nice. It worked