# winUSB install error

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, usb, usb-creator

While trying to install windows 7 to a usb stick I get this error during (or after) the syncing stage of winUSB.

[image]

It looks like the grub-install command failed to run, this also happened when trying to manually install grub [When installing Grub to a windows 7 install USB I get this error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492617/when-installing-grub-to-a-windows-7-install-usb-i-get-this-error)

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [winUSB install error installation failed! exit code 512](http://askubuntu.com/questions/496186/winusb-install-error-installation-failed-exit-code-512)

Answer (score 0):

try to format the USB Flash disk to NTFS file system, it works for me:

[WebUpd8: Create bootable Windows7 USB drive](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/create-bootable-windows-7-usb-drive.html)

Comment: It has nothing to do with the current filesystem on USB, because WinUSB formats it.