# How to fix "doesn't look like an EFI partition" with WinUSB?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, mount

Using WinUSB I get this error. I would appreciate any help as I'm trying to put Windows back on computer to please th' wifey, then dual boot so i can still use Ubuntu.

```
Installation failed !
Exit code: 512
Log:
Formating device...
Mounting...
mount: block device /home/lighthouse/Downloads/Windows 8.1 Update 1 Pro X64 PreActivated/Windows 8.1 Update 1 Pro X64 PreActivated.iso is write-protected, mounting read-only
Copying...
Installing grub...
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: error: /media/winusb_target_1412439366_7311 doesn't look like an EFI partition.
.
Error occured !
Syncing...
/usr/bin/winusb: line 78: 15592 Terminated              while true; do
    sleep 0.05; echo 'pulse';
done
Cleaning...
/usr/bin/winusb: line 78: 15971 Terminated              while true; do
    sleep 0.05; echo 'pulse';
done
Umounting and removing '/media/winusb_iso_1412439366_7311'...
Umounting and removing '/media/winusb_target_1412439366_7311'...
```

Comment: "grub-install: error: /media/winusb_target_1412439366_7311 doesn't look like an EFI partition." That is a windows problem: looks like you need an EFI partition.

Comment: Maybe related (very similar error): [Trouble installing Windows 7 via USB](http://askubuntu.com/questions/508409/trouble-installing-windows-7-via-usb)

Comment: how would i create an efi partition, there is an efi folder on th' drive too...

Comment: You would need to report this bug to whomever makes this "winusb" program, which does not appear to be part of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

If what you want is to create a bootable usb to install Windows 8, you must use the dd command in Ubuntu:

Open a terminal.

Run it:

```
dd if=/path/to/file.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

Note: Carefully check that the usb-stick is /dev/sdb

Comment: output for this command is dd: failed to open ‘/path/to/file.iso’: No such file or directory

Comment: You're supposed to replace the path with the path to your ISO and /dev/sdb with the location of your USB drive.

Answer (score 3):

That really depends on what type of bootable USB you want to make. If you want to make a classic MBR, BIOS bootable Windows USB try [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/539803/269282) solution.

If you want to make a USB to install Windows in UEFI mode, things are different:

1. Apply a GPT partition table to the USB drive and format it as FAT32 using GParted
2. Copy Windows files from DVD/ISO to USB using the file manager
3. Look for a `bootx64.efi` file in `efi/boot` folder in USB drive. If it doesn't exist extract it from the Windows ISO, `sources/install.wim` file by opening it with 7z unarchiver. You can find a `bootmgfw.efi` file in `./1/Windows/Boot/EFI`. Extract it, rename it to `bootx64.efi` and place it on USB in `efi/boot` folder.

Now the USB drive is UEFI bootable (but not BIOS) and can be used to install Windows in EFI mode. The complete guide is available [on my website](https://www.onetransistor.eu/2014/09/make-bootable-windows-usb-from-ubuntu.html) both for BIOS and UEFI.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, toggling the boot flag via parted fixed the problem

`parted /dev/sda set 2 boot on`

Choose disk and partition id accoriding to your system's configuration