# Installing for i386-pc platform Winusb

Tags: usb, windows, software-installation

So I began installing my windows.iso onto my flash drive, and the entire process was fine for the beginning. Now the window just reads installing for i386-pc platform, and the orange bar just keeps going back and forth. It really seems like there is no progress whatsoever. I'm going to let it run for more time, but I was wondering what I could do to fix this problem and finally install my windows.iso onto my flash drive using Winsub.

Comment: I can reproduce this. Mine has been running for 20 minutes. Did your process ever complete?

Comment: After about 30 minutes, my process moved on to the next step.

Comment: I can confirm - it literally just takes a long time. Let it run.

Comment: Same problem faced with fork [WoeUSB](https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB). Just waited, took around 10 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

This is strange. I suggest you apply the [512 error fix](https://askubuntu.com/a/539803/269282). Maybe you have an UEFI PC and GRUB is struggling to determine what kind of bootloader to install on USB. Adding the `target` argument will force the installation of a MBR bootloader.

---

### 512 error fix

You must edit the `winusb` script which is located probably in `/usr/bin` (I don't have it installed so I can't tell). Open it with any text editor with root permissions (e.g. `gksu gedit /usr/bin/winusb`). Now search for `grub-install` in that file (it may be on line 401) and change that line so it looks like this:

```
grub-install --target=i386-pc --boot-directory="$partitionMountPath/boot" "$device"
```

Save the script. Install the package `grub-pc-bin` and try again to use WinUSB.

**WinUSB only creates MBR bootable USB drives. If you want to install Windows in EFI mode a different method should be used.**

A manual bootable USB creation guide can be found on my [website](https://www.onetransistor.eu/2014/09/make-bootable-windows-usb-from-ubuntu.html).

---

If this doesn't work either, I suggest [the manual method](https://askubuntu.com/a/487970/269282).