# WinUSB - installation failed, 32512

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb, windows, ntfs

I want to create a bootable usb flash drive with Windows. But whatever USB flash I use - with NTFS or FAT32 or EXT4, I always get this error: `installation failed, 32512`

The size of iso file is 4.3Gb, but that shouldn't be a problem for NTFS or EXT4.

[image]

What's the matter?

P.S. I figure the button Refresh isn't working properly, it just doesn't the refresh the list of devices when I click on it.

Comment: You didnt flag the pen drive as bootable under gparted.

Comment: @Virusboy, why do you think so and how do I flag it?

Comment: From http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1509175&highlight=usb

`This is easy. I have done it. 

 1. sudo apt-get install gparted
 2. open gparted -> format stick to ntfs
 -> put bootable flag (right click in gparted - manage flags)

 3. extract win7.iso to usb stick or if you have live dvd just copy contents to usb stick`

Comment: @Virusboy, once again: why do you think I didn't set the flag "bootable"?

Comment: I had one of those ideas that seemed right

Comment: @Virusboy, the "boot" flag is set.

Comment: You can use mkusb-nox or guidus (the new version). These programs work with the current Ubuntu versions. See this link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu/837380#837380 and this link, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/gui#Installation

Answer (score 1):

You can use mkusb-nox or guidus (the new version). These programs work with the current Ubuntu versions. See this link,

[How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu/837380#837380)

and these links,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/gui#Installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/gui#Installation)

[Should work with minimal instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/gui#Should_work_with_minimal_instructions)

Answer (score 0):

> But whatever USB flash I use - with NTFS or FAT32 or EXT4

I keep seeing people recommend using a specific filesystem on USB drive. **Wrong!** WinUSB formats it. It doesn't care about your previous filesystem.

> The size of iso file is 4.3Gb, but that shouldn't be a problem for NTFS or EXT4.

It has nothing to do with EXT4. The USB drive will be NTFS if you use WinUSB.

> What's the matter?

Here is what I suggest:

1. Just in case, give that USB drive a label with no spaces.
2. Apply [this fix](https://askubuntu.com/a/539803/269282) to WinUSB and try again.

If it doesn't work, determine what type of computer is the one you are trying to install Windows on (with BIOS or UEFI) and how is its hard drive partitioned (GPT or MBR) - this if you care about not losing all partitions and follow [this manual guide on creating a bootable USB](https://www.onetransistor.eu/2014/09/make-bootable-windows-usb-from-ubuntu.html) on my website.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error then looked in the terminal and it kept returning this every time I clicked on install

```
sh: 1: gksudo: not found
```

So that exit code probably means that it can't find gksudo. After installing the gksu package I was able to install Windows to my USB without any errors popping up.

To install gksu:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gksu
```