# Win USB for Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: windows, live-usb, windows-10

There is no working Win USB software for Ubuntu 15.10 to create a bootable windows USB stick. There is another software to use for this purpose (or even a newer version of the Win USB)?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-with-ubuntu for the current answer. If 15.10 is different that topic needs updating.

Answer (score 2):

Just format drive in FAT32 fs and extract contents of Windows.iso to it.
Replace /dev/sdX with appropriate device:

```
mkfs.fat -F 32 /dev/sdX1 -n WINSETUP
mkdir -p /mnt/WINSETUP /mnt/WINSOURCE
mount /dev/sdX1 /mnt/WINSETUP
mount ~/Downloads/Windows.iso /mnt/WINSOURCE   
cp -rv /mnt/WINSOURCE/* /mnt/WINSETUP
```

Comment: It should be noted that this is a good method, but only for UEFI bootable media that should work with Windows 8 and newer.

Answer (score 1):

You can install WinUSB in Ubuntu 15.10. However, there are some things to consider:

- be sure you get the newest version that does not depend on `grub`, but on `grub-pc | grub-efi` otherwise you may make your system non bootable;
- you cannot make UEFI bootable flashdrives with it. Only the old MBR bootable type.

Here are the steps:

1. Download build from here, the second page: [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~colingille/+archive/ubuntu/freshlight/+packages).
2. Install the `deb` as you wish (Software Center, GDebi, Terminal).
3. Install `grub-pc-bin` package.
4. Edit `/usr/bin/winusb` to [fix the 512 error](https://askubuntu.com/q/496186/269282) by modifying `grub-install` instruction from script with `grub-install --target=i386-pc --boot-directory="$partitionMountPath/boot" "$device"`.

If the GUI is not starting you can still use the CLI `winusb`. Otherwise the only remaining solution is to compile from source with `./config.sh` and `make`.

I also wrote about this on my website [here](https://www.onetransistor.eu/2015/11/how-to-install-winusb-in-ubuntu-1510.html).